# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('jadwal_praks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('thnajrn_id', 10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('thnajrn_id')->references('id')->on('tahun_ajarans');
        $table->integer('prak_id', 10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('prak_id')->references('Prak_kode')->on('mata_praks');
        $table->integer('hari_id', 10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('hari_id')->references('id')->on('haris');
        $table->integer('jam_id', 10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('jam_id')->references('id')->on('jams');
        $table->integer('ruang_id', 10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('ruang_id')->references('id')->on('ruangs');
        $table->integer('kap_id', 10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('kap_id')->references('id')->on('kapasitas');

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->rememberToken();
    });
}
```

After run `php artisan migrate`

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be
>   only one auto co   lumn and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create
>   table `jadwal_praks` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment
>   primary key, `thnajrn_id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary
>   key, `prak_id` int unsigned not null auto   _increment primary key,
>   `hari_id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `jam_id`
>   int unsigned not nul   l auto_increment primary key, `ruang_id` int
>   unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `kap_id` int unsigned
>   not null auto_increment primary key, `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null, `remember_token` v   archar(100) null)
>   default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

And this

> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and
>   it must be defined as a key

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With my observation, I would say you should remove `default` value you added to the your foreign fields from (for example):

```
$table->integer('thnajrn_id', 10)->unsigned();
```

To:

```
$table->integer('thnajrn_id')->unsigned();
```

> PS: With a similar experience, I know presently this works with one of the projects I work with in Laravel 5.2.*

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 13):

When you use `$table->integer('thnajrn_id', 10)->unsigned()`; this means your setting the second parameter as true which represents AutoIncrement

**try**

```
table->integer('thnajrn_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
```

[More info](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/why-am-i-getting-a-database-error-on-migration)

Answer (score 1):

When you use  `$table->unsignedBigInteger('account_id')->nullable();` you can still get this same error, since `nullable()` produces a default value can produce that same error. So always leave your foreign key empty, neither `nullable` or `default(0)`