# I'm trying migration and it is throwing Exception Error?

Tags: laravel

**Code:**

```
` public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('month',4);
            $table->integer('price',7);
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }`
```

**Error:**
**QLSTATE[42000]:** Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key (SQL: create table `subscriptions` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `month` int
not null auto_increment primary key, `price` int not null auto_increment primary key, `status` tinyint not null default '1', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[42000\]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42053392/sqlstate42000-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1075-incorrect-table-definiti)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
*I solved my error doing this because we can't set a size on integers.*

```
 $table->integer('month');
 $table->integer('price');
```

Comment: You actually can. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65403153/7376590

Comment: use decimals for prices

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in integer is a boolean.

If true the field is autoincrement

Remove 4 and 7 from integer.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('month');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Francesco Gallo said the Second parameter in an integer is a boolean.
and if you are working with a price I highly recommend using a decimal instead of an integer.

so it would be better to write it like below:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('month');
            $table->decimal('price',5,3);
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```